# Randomize buttons in chatbot Messenger generic template

Tags: php, arrays, shuffle, messenger, chatbot

I want to randomize Answer_A;Answer_B;Answer_C in generic template chatbot.

```
  "message":{
"attachment":{
  "type":"template",    
  "payload":{
    "template_type":"generic",
    "elements":[
      {
        "title":"' . $res ['Question'] . '",  
    "image_url":"' . $res ['Picture'] . '",       
        "buttons":[
          {
            "type":"postback",
            "title":"' . $res ['Answer_A'] . '",
            "payload":"Answer_A-' . $res ['id'] . '"
          },
          {
            "type":"postback",
            "title":"' . $res ['Answer_B'] . '",
            "payload":"Answer_B-' . $res ['id'] . '"
          },
      {
            "type":"postback",
            "title":"' . $res ['Answer_C'] . '",
            "payload":"Answer_C-' . $res ['id'] . '"
          }
```

It's a simple trivia chatbot and questions are loaded from *csv file:

```
Category;Question;Answer A;Answer B;Answer C;Correct Answer
Name;Sample question?;Lorem;Ipsum;Dolores;a
```

Do you have any idea how shuffle the answers, which shows?

Answer (score 0):

Think of elements as an $array. What you need is just shuffling the array of elements before sending the template.